# Create a function that makes the query with all the elements of an array one by one with postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, function, postgis, pgrouting

I am preparing a function for PgRouting that is based on another function that I have also prepared. The purpose of this is to make a function that by entering the origin and destination coordinates of a route as a response. I got it from point to point with pgr_dijkstra. Now I need to do the same, but with pgr_dijkstravia. This is based on an ARRAY, you force the route to go through specific points that you enter. A kind of Google maps, you can put the points you want and the route makes you pulling those points that you have imposed. I got the first function with ARRAY and it would be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrk3_dijkstravia( 
IN edges_subset regclass, 
IN via_vertices ANYARRAY,
OUT seq INTEGER, 
OUT path_id integer,
OUT path_seq integer,
OUT start_vid BIGINT,
OUT end_vid BIGINT,
OUT node BIGINT,
OUT edge BIGINT,
OUT name TEXT, 
OUT cost FLOAT, 
OUT agg_cost FLOAT,
OUT azimuth FLOAT,
OUT route_agg_cost FLOAT,
OUT route_readable TEXT, 
OUT route_geom geometry ) 
RETURNS SETOF record 
AS 
$BODY$ 
WITH dijkstra AS 
    (SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstravia( 'SELECT gid as id, reverse_cost, * FROM ' || $1,
    $2::BIGINT[], true ,false)), 
get_geom AS
    (SELECT dijkstra.*, ways.name,
    CASE WHEN dijkstra.node = ways.source THEN the_geom ELSE ST_Reverse(the_geom) 
    END 
    AS route_geom FROM dijkstra LEFT JOIN ways ON (edge = gid) ORDER BY seq) 
SELECT 
seq,
path_id,
path_seq,
start_vid,
end_vid,
node,
edge,
name, 
cost,
agg_cost, 
route_agg_cost, 
degrees(ST_azimuth(ST_StartPoint(route_geom), 
ST_EndPoint(route_geom))) AS azimuth, 
ST_Astext(route_geom),
route_geom
FROM get_geom ORDER BY seq; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

And an example of querying a view that I have already created would be this:

```
select * from wrk3_dijkstravia('vehiculo_tiempo', ARRAY [42, 64, 85])
```

And he returns the route to me. But the variables of the ARRAY are ids of the nodes and with vision to be used by a client is not viable. So here comes the following function, which is based on this first:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrk1_fromAtoB(
    IN edges_subset regclass,
    IN x ANYARRAY, IN y ANYARRAY,
    OUT seq INTEGER,
    OUT gid BIGINT,
OUT name TEXT,
OUT distancia_m NUMERIC,
OUT distancia_total NUMERIC, 
OUT cost NUMERIC, 
OUT agg_cost NUMERIC,
OUT azimuth FLOAT,
OUT route_agg_cost NUMERIC,
OUT route_readable TEXT, 
OUT route_geom geometry )

RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    final_query TEXT;
BEGIN

    final_query :=
        FORMAT( $$
            WITH
            vertices AS (
                SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
                WHERE id IN (
                    SELECT source FROM %1$I
                    UNION
                    SELECT target FROM %1$I)
            ),
            dijkstra AS (
                SELECT *
                FROM wrk3_dijkstravia(
                    '%1$I',
                    ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%2$s, %3$s), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
            ))
            SELECT
                seq,
                gid,
                dijkstra.name,
                TRUNC (ways.length_m::numeric) AS distancia_m,
                TRUNC (sum(length_m::numeric) OVER (ORDER BY seq), 2) as distancia_total,
                ROUND (dijkstra.cost::numeric, 2) AS cost,
                ROUND (dijkstra.agg_cost::numeric, 2) as agg_cost,
                azimuth,
                route_agg_cost::NUMERIC,
                route_readable,
                route_geom AS geom
            FROM dijkstra LEFT JOIN ways ON dijkstra.edge = ways.gid;$$,
        edges_subset, x,y);
    RAISE notice '%', final_query;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE final_query;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And the query would be this:

```
select * from wrk1_fromAtoB('vehiculo_distancia',  ARRAY[-7.559516429901122,   -7.561619281768799, -7.563893795013428], ARRAY [ 43.01592861164031, 43.01329278981061, 43.00988801917453])
```

But the mistake he gives me is the following:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 15: ...        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point({-7.559516...
```

This is because in ST_Point I am getting all the coordinates:

```
dijkstra AS (
                SELECT *
                FROM wrk3_dijkstravia(
                    'vehiculo_distancia',
                    ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point({-7.559516429901122,-7.561619281768799,-7.563893795013428}, {43.01592861164031,43.01329278981061,43.00988801917453}), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
```

What I want is for the ST_Point function to go through the two arrays one by one and as many times as data exists in the array

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to shorten a bit and I have this DO, but it only makes me raise.

```
DO 
$do$
DECLARE 
    x numeric[];
    arr numeric[] := ARRAY [[-7.563947439193725, 43.02141169991877], [-7.56184458732605, 43.01576387609036],[-7.5599563121795645, 43.006741968861974]];
BEGIN

    FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr
    LOOP 
         RAISE notice  'WITH
            vertices AS (
                SELECT * FROM ways_vertices_pgr
                WHERE id IN (
                    SELECT source FROM ways
                    UNION
                    SELECT target FROM ways)
            ),
            dijkstra AS (
                SELECT *
                FROM wrk3_dijkstravia(
                    ways,

                   ARRAY[(SELECT id FROM vertices
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(%,%), 4258) LIMIT 1)]
            ))' ,x[1], x[2];
        END LOOP;
END;
$do$
```

But I need to put it into my function. Let's see if someone can help me.
Thank you